# Action Required Google Play Policies. We have determined your app contains code to facilitate Disruptive Ads

Tags: google-play, admob

I have one Web-view app in Google Play store. (only for Adroid)
According to Google, they found that my app is not compliant with the Disruptive Ads policy.
However, my App only has one interstitial ad by Google Admob...

Thus, Google Admob is making Disruptive Ads all the time?
Or should I remove the interstitial ad?

Google Play vs Google Admob, nonsense...

Comment: Does the appearance of the interstitial have any logic? When does it appear?

Comment: Hi, any news on this? I got the same message and I don't know why.

Comment: I think Google Play really needs to be sued via a class action lawsuit over these vague and baseless rejections.

Comment: did you solved it？

Comment: Any input on this?